# How to copy files to more than one location using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build, copy

I'd like to define a Gradle task that copies files to four different directories. It seems that the copy task only allows a single target location.

```
// https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files
task copyAssets(type: Copy) {
  from 'src/docs/asciidoc/assets'
  //into ['build/asciidoc/html5/assets', 'build/asciidoc/pdf/assets']
  into 'build/asciidoc/pdf/assets'
}


task gen(dependsOn: ['copyAssets', 'asciidoctor']) << {
    println "Files are generated."
}
```

How can I copy the files without defining four different tasks?

My current solution is:

```
// https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files
task copyAssetsPDF(type: Copy) {
  from 'src/docs/asciidoc/assets'
  into 'build/asciidoc/pdf/assets'
}
task copyAssetsHTML5(type: Copy) {
  from 'src/docs/asciidoc/assets'
  into 'build/asciidoc/html5/assets'
}
task copyAssetsDB45(type: Copy) {
  from 'src/docs/asciidoc/assets'
  into 'build/asciidoc/docbook45/assets'
}
task copyAssetsDB5(type: Copy) {
  from 'src/docs/asciidoc/assets'
  into 'build/asciidoc/docbook5/assets'
}


task gen(dependsOn: ['copyAssetsPDF', 'copyAssetsHTML5', 'copyAssetsDB45', 'copyAssetsDB5', 'asciidoctor']) << {
    println "Files are generated."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions is to make a single task with a number of copy specifications like:

```
task copyAssets << {
    copy {
        from 'src/docs/asciidoc/assets'
        into 'build/asciidoc/pdf/assets'
    }
    copy {
        from 'src/docs/asciidoc/assets'
        into 'build/asciidoc/pdf/assets'
    }
}
```

Or you can do it within a loop:

```
//an array containing destination paths
def copyDestinations = ['build/asciidoc/pdf/assets', 'build/asciidoc/html5/assets']

//custom task to copy into all the target directories
task copyAssets << {
    //iterate over the array with destination paths
    copyDestinations.each { destination ->
        //for every destination define new CopySpec
        copy {
            from 'src/docs/asciidoc/assets'
            into destination
        }
    }
}
```